# Why can't immutable UDFs be called within certain clauses of a CTE in Redshift?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, immutability, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

The issue can be simplified to this, where, within a view, any CTE referring to some_immutable_func breaks, except in the WHERE, HAVING clauses, resulting in the following error::

```
create or replace function some_immutable_func ()
  returns int
  immutable as $$
    SELECT 1
  $$ language sql;

create view some_view as
WITH some_cte AS (
  SELECT immutable_func()
)
SELECT * FROM some_cte;

FATAL:  Query processing failed due to an internal error.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "immutable_func"
SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.



-- but this is okay
create view some_view as
WITH some_cte AS (
  SELECT * FROM some_table
  WHERE ...some_immutable_func()...
  HAVING ...some_immutable_func()...
)
SELECT * FROM some_cte;
CREATE VIEW
```

Built-in immutable UDFs such as ABS(-3) work fine. Simply changing the UDF to be stable fixes the issue, but I am looking to optimize query performance within a complex view, where apparently the stable nature of a certain UDF slows it down nearly 100x. Ideally, I would also like to minimize changes to the view's structure, hopefully doing a simple replace-all instead of rearranging all references to the UDF into WHERE and HAVING clauses.

I believe the problem may be with the query optimizer, but I'm surprised there is little information out there regarding the cryptic/finer details of Redshift/postgres and immutability.

EDIT: I've also discovered that changing the UDF language to python seems to work fine. However, it seems to have quite slow performance in my specific use case, potentially worse than just using the STABLE SQL UDF.

Comment: Figured out a weird fix: simply add a reference to the immutable UDF in the main SELECT, then the view can be processed normally.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. We will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to confirm that this has been resolved since the question was posted.

The provided example now works as expected.